# Preventing acts of spam

Tags: support, best-practices, spam

I came across a number of posts being sabotaged by a couple of new users. How do we prevent such indecent acts?

Comment: Flag for mod attention, downvote, and move on with life.

Comment: What kind of sabotage are we talking about, spam in answers? Spam in suggested edits? Vandalism?

Comment: I also noticed that incident. I don't think they are "new users"; in fact, I suppose it was a single user. Both accounts were unregistered and based on their comments it seems they've been active on this site before. Be it as it may, I also saw people commenting under their "answers", which I think is not good practice: Don't feed the troll.

Comment: This has been reported in Chem.SE as well. See these posts: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/whats-the-point-of-users-commenting-the-url-of-the-question-itself-in-the-comme and https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/edits-by-anonymous-user-and-approved-by-community-bot. If you think the activity is severe, flag for mod attention. They will judge the severity and contact the staffs if needed.

Answer (score 11):

That's what flags are for! See [the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) for more details.